# How can you click the Screen using AppleScript?

Tags: click, applescript

So I tried to test the click at command using a test script and I got the error -25200 and everywhere I looked, I don't see why I got this error.

```
property mousex : 1
property mousey : 1
property screenx: 2559
property screeny: 1599

tell application "System Events"



    repeat 100 times
         click at {mousex mod screenx, mousey mod screeny}
         set mousex to mousex + 100
         set mousey to mousey + 100
         delay 0.2
     end repeat

end tell
end run
```

Comment: One way would be trying to click out of bounds - is your screen that size?

Comment: I use a 13-inch macbook air which has a screen-size of 2560 by 1600. I found no online mention of error -25200, so I thought I should ask it.

Comment: The error is an unhelpful `kAXErrorFailure`.  You might try lowering the screen values by one, since the coordinates start at {0, 0}.

Comment: Testing your code, I seem to end up with errors when the GUI changes: i.e., when something that the script clicked pulls up a menu, closes a window, or creates a popup. Since you've added no delays in the repeat loop, the script is firing as fast as it can, so I suspect it's getting ahead of the changes in the GUI (which are comparatively slow operations), so the clicks are landing on regions of the screen that are in the process of being invalidated. Try adding `delay .2` before `end repeat` and see if you still get errors.

Comment: @red_menace I did that, I still got the error

Comment: @TedWrigley I don't think that the popups are the problem since I'm using this scipt to paint on an empty photoshop canvas while there is no GUI even active. Also, the delay didn't help.

Comment: If you know you’re painting on a specific GUI element, then you should target that element’s containing process (i.e. Photoshop), just for extra reliability and to avoid clicking an element of another process you didn’t intend to.  But, I am skeptical about whether this is going to do what you want.  Does the `click at` command successfully result in a point painted onto the canvas ?  It’s possible it might, but, on balance, unlikely.  `click at` doesn’t actually click the mouse button.

Comment: What would you using instead of click at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `click at` is not the right approach in this situation.
Something like [MouseTools](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/MouseTools/MouseTools.html) would fit your needs better. The correct way of doing this would be:

```
property screenX : 1439
property screenY : 899

repeat with mousePos from 1 to 100
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/mousetools -x " & ((mousePos * 100) mod screenX) & " -y " & ((mousePos * 100) mod screenY) & " -leftClick"
    delay 0.1
end repeat
end run
```

Note that I made a few changes: I don't think having two variables with the exact same value at all times is efficient so I changed both of them to `mousePos`. But as you can see, there is no `set mousePos to mousePos + 100` but instead I used `repeat with`. Repeat with automatically increases the variable by one every time it loops, so I had to add the `* 100`. Also, the screenX and screenY values are changed when using MouseTools, you can get your screen size by running this script and moving your mouse to the bottom right:

```
repeat 10 times
    set mousePos to do shell script "/usr/local/bin/mousetools -location"
    display notification mousePos
    delay 1
end repeat
```

The end result when running this code in [Affinity Photo](https://affinity.serif.com/en-us/photo/), a similar product to Photoshop, which I saw you were planning to use it for:

[image]

---

<sub>The code above was tested in macOS 11.4 Beta on a 13-inch MacBook Air 2019</sub>

---

EDIT: As user3439894 said:

> There is also: [cliclick](https://github.com/BlueM/cliclick)

I decided to rewrite the script to use cliclick because cliclick seems more modern and also faster:

```
property screenX : 1439
property screenY : 899
repeat with mousePos from 1 to 100
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/cliclick c:" & ((mousePos * 100) mod screenX) & "," & ((mousePos * 100) mod screenY)
    delay 0.1
end repeat
end run
```

This works the exact same way as the script above. As you can see, the screen size is still the same as when using MouseTools, still no idea why that is. If you want to get the location with cliclick, use this script:

```
repeat 10 times
    set mousePos to do shell script "/usr/local/bin/cliclick p:."
    display notification mousePos
    delay 1
end repeat
```

---

<sub>The code above was tested in macOS 11.4 Beta on a 13-inch MacBook Air 2019</sub>

---

Both cliclick and MouseTools can be installed using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) by typing the command `brew install cliclick` or `brew install mousetools` in the Terminal.

Comment: There is also: [cliclick](https://github.com/BlueM/cliclick)

Comment: BTW Both are available as pre-compiled binaries if you don't use Homebrew.

Comment: @user3439894 I am aware of that, but the user would have to move those files to the right directory.

Comment: RE: "I am aware of that, but the user would have to move those files to the right directory" --  What's the right _directory_? One can place them wherever one wants.  I know some uses that place them in the `bin` _directory_ within their home _directory_. And manually moving them to e.g. `/usr/local/bin/` is just not a big deal! Also, not everyone uses Homebrew and for those that don't and just want one of both of these particular _third-party utilities_, installing thru Homebrew would be ridiculous as it now takes several GB of space just for Homebrew and it's dependencies.

Comment: As **MouseTools** never even made it to a version 1 release, (it's 11 years old and the last update was 18 Nov 2012 to v0.5), I too doubt it will be updated for **macOS** 12, however, the _source code_ is available and I did not see a copyright notice in it, so maybe someone will update it if possible.