# Click with AppleScript not working in chrome game

Tags: macos, applescript

Im trying to auto click some part of a google chrome unity game, but it's not actually clicking.

The problem is the unitiy game part of the screen, because when I put another coordinate in any other part of the screen, it works perfectly fine.
Any ideas?
This is my code

```
tell application "System Events"
  key code 53
  delay 1
  click at {1114, 202}
end tell
```

Comment: Could you provide either link or DOM-Structure of the site? Otherwise, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67129103/how-can-you-click-the-screen-using-applescript/68089104#68089104)